# Short cut method to draw multiple dots with label on a curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

Let us consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6pt]
\draw (1,0)--(20,0); 
\foreach \x in {1,...,20}{
\draw[fill] (\x,0) circle (1.5pt);
}   
\foreach \x/\a in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4,5/5,6/6,7/7,8/8,9/9,10/10,11/11,12/12,13 /13,14/14,15/15,16/16,17/17,18/18,19/19,20/20}{
\node[below] at (\x,0) {\a};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: output]

Whenever I have used the following short cut technique gives errors.

```
\foreach \x/\a in {1/1,...,20/20}{
  \node[below] at (\x,0) {\a};
 }
```

How can I do this by short cut method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same counter to do the label.

```
 \draw[fill] (\x,0)node[below]{$\x$} circle (1.5pt);
```

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
 \draw (1,0)--(20,0); 
 \foreach \x in {1,...,20}{
 \draw[fill] (\x,0)node[below]{$\x$} circle (1.5pt);
 }   
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

**ps:** just to inform, you can control the distance between the label and the dot making use of `below=5pt` for example.

Comment: Can you tell me please, why it gives me error \foreach \x in {1/2,...,20}{
 \draw[fill] (\x,0)node[below]{$\x$} circle (1.5pt);
 } . But \foreach \x in {1.5,...,20}{
 \draw[fill] (\x,0)node[below]{$\x$} circle (1.5pt);
 } it works well. How can we use _x/y_ type label using short cut method?

Comment: Hum, hard to say (in English)! Please, read the user guide. www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(20,2)
\psline(0,1)(20,1)
\foreach \x in {0,...,20}{\qdisk(\x,1){2pt}\uput{10pt}[-90](\x,1){$\x\mathstrut$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A PSTricks solution with the aid of the powerful [`xfp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfp) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*\Total{\fpeval{\maxNumber+1}}
\newcommand*\Unit{\fpeval{11.5/\maxNumber}}

\def\maxNumber{20}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.35)(11.6,0)
\psset{unit = \Unit}
  \psline(0,0)(\maxNumber,0)
  \multido{\i = 0+1}{\Total}{%
    \psdot(\i,0)
    \uput[270](\i,0){\small $\i$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that all you have to do is choose the value of `\maxNumber` and then the drawing will be adjusted automatically.